# MacOS bash alias breaks at mv command

Tags: bash, macos, alias

I am trying to rename about 40 images ("1.png" to "40.png").

This first command works in the terminal:

```
user$ ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.png"; done
```

But I'd like to make that command into an alias in ~/.bash_profile.

```
alias rename-png="ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "&n.png"; done"

alias rename-png="ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv /"$f/" /"&n.png/"; done"

rename-png() {
    ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.png"; done
}
```

The first alias does not work, which I assumed was because the quotes were not escaped. However even while escaping the double quotes, the command breaks at `mv`. I also tried it in a function, and that did not work either.

The error:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ex. `alias l='ls -lp'`  So modify your alias definition, enclose the part after the = in ' quotes.

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: BTW, *backslashes*, not forward slashes, are used for escaping in double quotes -- and you need to escape `$`s as well (though it would be more sensible to use single quotes if you were to use an alias, which is -- as chepner says -- the Wrong Thing for this use case).

Comment: In hindsight, thats my bad, I originally used backslashes when testing. I whipped this answer up real fast as an example. I also tried escaping the money sign and single quotes to start as well, it still breaks at mv. Looking into the not parsing output of ls at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an alias for something this complex; just use a function. Further, don't try to use the output of `ls`. Use a `for` loop with a pattern:

```
rename-png () {
  i=0
  for f in ./*; do
    mv "$f" "$i.png"
    i=$((i + 1))
  done
}
```

Comment: Might make it `local i=0` to avoid leaving a global variable `i` around (granted, yes, the original alias would have done that too).

Comment: I'll add my usual plea for `mv -n` or `mv -i` to avoid overwriting files in case of a name conflict. For example, if there are files named "0.png" and "1.png", it'll start by renaming 0.png to 1.png (overwriting the original 1.png), then rename that same file from 1.png to 2.png. Result: 0.png becomes 2.png, and 1.png vanishes without a trace.

Comment: i put this in a test.sh, i get:  test.sh: line 9: `rename-png': not a valid identifier

Comment: You are running your script with `sh`, not `bash`; hyphens are not a valid function name character in POSIX shell.

Comment: @UsernameError3, ...which is to say, change the name to `rename_png` and it'll work across all POSIX shells.

Comment: Thank you, the hyphen was the issue. I have yet to have time to learn *nix scripting, i gotta book on it, but not enough time.